# Using my NavigationController with my ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, slidingmenu, ecslidingviewcontroller

**What I'm trying to do**

---

If started creating my App. I've got a `NavigationController` as my `rootViewController`. When the app is started it will open my `LoginViewController`. In there I do the `Login-Procedure`, if everything is fine. I'll start my `ECSlidingViewController`. Which has a **Menu** (`UITableView`) and a **MainView** (`UITableView`).

Until here everything is working fine. I can swipe and it show's my menu. Now the problem is starting. When I press a menu-item it perfectly starts my new ViewController and show's the content. But there it still show's the same `NavigationBar` - like in the `ECSlidingViewController`. So I got no possibility to tell the user what he is looking at, also I need to show him sometimes new options in the `NavigationBar`.

**Question**

---

How can I fix this problem? I'd always like to show the `NavigationBar` of the specific ViewController I'm actually using. If you guy's have some Codesnippets or a good Idea how to handle this problem. Please leave a comment bellow.

If you need codesnippets or something else, tell me I'll upload it! Thank you in advance!

**Code**

---

This is how I start my ECSlidingMenu:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginPush" sender:self.view];
```

This is how I'll start a new ViewController:

```
UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

**Pictures***

---

[image: Structure of the Storyboard:]

Comment: Have you changed the appearance of UINavigation bar when it moved to new ViewController's view?

Comment: Show the code for the relationship between the root navigation controller and the switch to the sliding controller (does it become the new root?).

Comment: yes it should show a text and a button.... but it's allways showing the navigationbar of my ECSlidingViewController. Idk where the problem lies. I'm using one NavigationController for the whole app btw. @wain give me a minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to change your structure so that the `ECSlidingViewViewController` is the root view controller. This can either be from the start of the app or you can switch the root after login. The top view controller of the sliding controller should then be a navigation controller and you should set the root and push other view controllers into that navigation controller.

What you currently have breaks the link between the view controllers and the navigation controller because only the sliding view controller is pushed into the stack and its title (nothing about its `navigationItem` ever changes).

Probably the easiest solution would be to change the initial view controller in the storyboard (to the sliding view controller). In this case the login view would be presented as the root view of the navigation controller (which would be the top view). Then, after login you push the next view controller and then (after the animation completes) remove the login view controller from the nav stack.

Comment: Hey Wain, I could fix it with you're help! Everything is now working perfectly fine! Thank you!